# NoncommutativeMultiply, wedge product and exterior algebra

Tags: algebra, differential-geometry

I would like want to automate some calculations involving wedge products of differential form of different order. Is it possible to define a NoncommutativeMultiply function that has the properties of the wedge product? It's easy to make it bilinear under addition, i.e.:

```
(A_+B_)**C_ := A**C + B**C; A_**(B_+C_) := A**B + A**C;
```

but I have no idea how to make it bilinear under multiplication by a scalar/0-form... the best I could come up with was to define scalar coefficients as objects that always have the form f[something], and then define:

```
(a_f*A)**B := Times[a,A**B];
```

so it will perform simplifications like `(f[1]*A)**B = f[1]*(A**B)`, but then it doesn't simplify numerical coefficients, like `(2*A)**B = 2*(A**B)`. I could do `(a_Integer*A)**B := Times[a,A**B];` but then what about rational, real or complex numbers? Like this it never ends, and I feel there must be a much more elegant solution.

Moreover, I'd like to define differential forms of different degrees, and the graded commutativity rule, such that if A is a p-form and B is a q-form (sorry for the pseudocode):

```
A**B = A**B  (if A and B are in alphanumeric order),
A**B = (-1)^(p q) B**A (otherwise).
```

I feel like there should be a way to define n-form objects that carry with them the information of the value of n, and such that if n=0 they coincide with normal symbols and numerical factors. Any suggestion?

Comment: TensorProduct and Wedge are your main containers. Consult  TensorExpand and TensorReduce Help pages.  Generally speaking, don't work with definitions of operations. Use algebraic transformations by Replace with Patterns.  For general simplification processes its essential to declare symbols as scalars, vectors, tensor of type (m,n) in order to get the tensor algebra gears working.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Side question: why do you say to avoid working with definitions of operations?

Comment: Does this package on Mathsource do what you want? https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/683 The description indicates it does wedge products and exterior derivatives. You can also search on Google, entering keywords like 'wedge product exterior algebra mathematica' to search for packages. That's how I found the link above.

Comment: @spinoro: We all started as beginners in Mathematica with definitions  like 'TensorProduc[ a_?NumericQ + b_ , c___] := a*TensorProduct[b,c]'   etc. This is overloading any input of TensorProduct expressions on thousands of internal calls with check of arguments each time of internal occurence and passing arguments. Such simplifcations should be done only at a few points of calculations by applying specialized  dedicated simplification command using pattern replacements.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks. So, if I understood, instead of defining operations via their axioms (linearity, (anti-)commutativity etc.), which wastes a load of resources each time the operation is called, I should apply a bunch of pattern replacement rules which enforce said axioms, just a few times when I have control over it. Correct?